# Need to pull names of people who make more than 100,000 from array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of people that has objects with details about them. For example, "Bob Cratchit" might have an age of 30, a set of skills: "JS, CSS, Python", and a salary of "113000". I want to first check if he has a salary of over 100000, and if so, return his first and last name.

I have tried various methods of .map and .filter, and even tried nesting them. My .map works when I use the console, returning all the names, and the .filter returns all info on people that have > 100000 salary, but I can't seem to do both.

```
let people = [{
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "Frank",
    "lastName": "Herbert",
    "job": "Lead Software Engineer",
    "Skills": ["JavaScript", "C#", "SQL", "HTML", "CSS", "SCRUM 
Master"],
    "Salary": 120196
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "firstName": "Joan",
    "lastName": "Armorett",
    "job": "Jr Software Developer",
    "Skills": ["JavaScript", "HTML", "CSS"],
    "Salary": 70000
}

// This is the .map function, which will show me all of the names, 
regardless of their salary.
let answer = people.map((person) => {return person.firstName});

// This is the .filter function, which will show me all data, not 
just names on everyone with a salary of 100000 or higher.
let answer = people.filter((person) => {
    return person.Salary > 100000;
});
```

What I would like is some way to have both: only show results of people who make 100000 or more, and only show those people's names, not other data on them.

Comment: First, filter them by salary. It results in a new array, just use `map` on that new array. Like this: `people.filter((x) => x.Salary > 100000).map((x) => x.firstName)`.

Comment: it's quite unclear, what you like to get. do you want to have two result sets?

Comment: I would like to return a list of people that have a salary of more than 100000, but only display their names.

Comment: then filter first and then get the names.

Answer (score 0):

The code below uses filter and map functions chained together. Filter returns an array of all the objects having salary property>100000 and map takes the array returned from filter and returns the objects firstname and lastname property . In the end the array is spread out with the spread operator `(...)` returning it as text.

```js
let people = [{
   "id": 1,
   "firstName": "Frank",
   "lastName": "Herbert",
   "job": "Lead Software Engineer",
   "Skills": ["JavaScript", "C#", "SQL", "HTML", "CSS", "SCRUMMaster"],
   "Salary": 120196
},
{
   "id": 2,
   "firstName": "Joan",
   "lastName": "Armorett",
   "job": "Jr Software Developer",
   "Skills": ["JavaScript", "HTML", "CSS"],
   "Salary": 70000
}]
var t=people.filter((e)=>e.Salary>100000).map((e)=>e.firstName+" "+e.lastName)
console.log(...t)
```

Comment: I think this answer could benefit from a higher quality explanation. "This will do" doesn't really add much value.

Comment: This does work, but do you know if there is a way to stop it from being an array and simply return text? Sorry if I was unspecific in the question, and thanks for the answer!

Answer (score -1):

You could use reduce to do this:

```
    const peopleWhoMakeOverHundredThou = people.reduce((acc, el) => {
    if (el.Salary > 100000){
    const name = `${el.firstName} ${el.lastName}`
    acc.push(name);
     }
    return acc;
    },[])
    console.log(peopleWhoMakeOverHundredThou)
```

If you're only expecting one to be higher and wanted to return a single string instead of any array, you can just adjust as follows:

```
    const peopleWhoMakeOverHundredThou = people.reduce((acc, el) => {
    if (el.Salary > 100000){
    const name = `${el.firstName} ${el.lastName}`
    acc+=name;
     }
    return acc;
    },'')
    console.log(peopleWhoMakeOverHundredThou)
```